# Choosing a Data Model for a Workout App: Unique IDs for Sets vs. Exercise ID + Set Number composite

Tags: database, data-modeling

I'm developing a workout app where each exercise can have multiple sets. I'm trying to decide on the best data model for managing these sets. Specifically, I'm torn between two approaches and would like some guidance on which one would be more suitable for my use case.

**Approach 1: Unique IDs for Each Set**

In this approach, each set has its own unique ID, independent of the exercise it belongs to.

**Approach 2: Exercise ID + Set Number**

In this approach, I use a combination of the exercise ID and a set number to identify each set (e.g., Exercise A has sets A-1, A-2, A-3). Basically a composite key.

My question is, which approach would be more suitable for a workout app where users might dynamically change the number of reps (or other parameters) for individual sets? I want to ensure the data model I choose allows for easy tracking and updating of set details while maintaining a structured system. You can also add exercises dynamically.
Any advice or insights on these two approaches, or alternative suggestions, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For the unfit people among us it may help to define what a set and a rep is. Do either of these models require a user to set up a new "header" record on the fly i.e. if they don't make the reps number? That would defnitely be a usability problem